# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'twilio'

Tags: python, twilio

I developed a small program with twilio a few days ago and it was working perfectly until today. When I run the code I get the error "No module named 'twilio'". I already tried uninstalling and reinstalling it, I also checked, and don't have any archive called twillio, the python version i'm using is the latest, the library seems to be correctly installed... Any idea of what may be happening?

The line of code that im trying to run is `from twilio.rest import Client`

Comment: wdym by `don't have any archive called twillio` ?

Comment: That sounds to me, like you have not activated your virtual environment correctly. Can you check that? Otherwise, reinstall ```twilio``` in your current environment.

Answer (score 1):

1. If you are installed 'twilio' in a virtual environment then you are probably not activating and using it properly.
2. The error can also be caused due to Circular import, which happens when you have a file named 'twilio' in the same directory as the program file. You can prevent that by changing the name to something else.
3. If you have more than one version of python you are probably using the wrong version, so select the correct version of the interpreter for python in your IDE.

Comment: Thanks for answering! I just checked all of those things, and everything seems normal. I discovered that if I run the code from the IDLE I get that error, but if I run it from the python console directly, it works perfectly. Have any idea of why?

Comment: I think the problem with running from the IDE is point 3 in my answer.

Comment: Yes, that makes total sense, but I only have one version installed. In fact I changed my computer recently so I should only have the lastest version : / ... Thanks for your help!